# MediaType for MessagePack in Jersey webservice

Tags: java, jersey, content-type, msgpack

I am working on a simple Jersey Restful web service; and this web service needs to consume Messagepack request and produce a MessagePack response.

Right now I am using "application/octet-stream" to read MessagePack message in byte[] and converting into Entity bean & viceversa. But I am looking for something like MediaType.APPLICATION_MSGPK which can does this conversion under the hood and saves processing time.

```
@POST
@Path("/msgpk")
@Consumes("application/octet-stream")
@Produces("application/octet-stream")
public byte[] predictFlightAvailabilityForMsgPack(byte[] predictionRequestBiteStream) {
        PredictionRequest request = null;
        PredictionResponse response = null;
        byte[] responsebytes = null;
        MessagePack msgpack = new MessagePack();
        try {
        // here I am manually converting the byte[] steam to Entity bean
        request = msgpack.read(predictionRequestBiteStream, PredictionRequest.class);
        if (request != null) {
        response = dispatchRequest(request);
            // here manually converting the Entity bean to byte[]
        responsebytes = msgpack.write(response);
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responsebytes;
}
```

I have been searching for a solution; but could not find any ware.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am using the "javax.ws.rs" libraries; so javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType class should accept the MessagePack format.